# No bootable device, hard drive missing

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bootable-media

Acer E15 laptop
Win10

Sequence of events

1. Blue screen of death
2. power off/reboot
3. No Bootable Device
4. BIOS HDD shows 'None'
5. boot with windows recovery usb
6. Tried all windows recovery options, none work
7. launch cmd.exe from windows recovery
8. DISKPART> list disk

   Disk ###  Status    Size    Free

   ---

   Disk 0    Online    28 GB     0 B

   DISKPART> select disk 0

   Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

   DISKPART> list partition

   Partition ###    Type        Size        Offset

   ---

   Partition 1      Primary     28 GB       1024 KB

Any guidance on how to get my hard drive back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you report points to your hard disk having died a sudden death.
Not an uncommon event.
The chances of bringing it back to life are pretty slim.
You may try reseating all cable connectors on the off-chance that it is just a bad contact, but beyond that it's probably not worth investing any time.
Just buy a new one and restore your system from the last backup.